# How to put two divs created programmatically side by side?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I put the two divs side by side? What if I have more than 2 divs and I want to put them all side by side? I found that if they are canvas, they are automatically placed side by side. This is not true for divs.

In additional, how come the button's value doesn't change the text on the button? I was expecting "Commit" to show up but it didn't.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML5 Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function draw () {

    var displayHeight = 200;
    var displayWidth = 100;
    var container = document.getElementById("container");

    var Div = {
        elemOne  : CreateRectDivElement (displayWidth/2,displayHeight/10*8),
        elemTwo  : CreateRectDivElement (displayWidth/2,displayHeight/10*8),
        buttonCommit: CreateButtonElement (displayWidth,displayHeight/10*2)
    };

     Div.buttonCommit.type="button";
     Div.buttonCommit.value="Commit";
     Div.elemOne.style.border = '1px solid black';
     Div.elemTwo.style.border = '1px solid black';

    container.appendChild (Div.buttonCommit);
    container.appendChild (document.createElement("br"));
    container.appendChild (Div.elemOne);
    container.appendChild (Div.elemTwo);


  }

  function CreateRectCanvasElement(width, height)
  {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.style.position = 'relative';
    canvas.style.border = '1px solid black';

    canvas.style.width = width + 'px';
    canvas.style.height= height + 'px';


    return canvas;
  }

  function CreateButtonElement(width, height)
  {
    var element = document.createElement('button');
    element.style.width = width + 'px';
    element.style.height = height + 'px';

    return element;
  }

  function CreateDivElement()
  {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    return div;
  }

  function CreateRectDivElement (width, height)
  {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.width = width + 'px';
    div.style.height= height + 'px';

    return div;
  }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="draw()">
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 for having code that's not ugly as hell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### DIV issue

Use `display: inline-block;` or `float: left;` in the style.

```
 Div.elemOne.style.display = 'inline-block';
 Div.elemTwo.style.display = 'inline-block';
```

#### Button issue

The value is not in every browser the caption of  the button. Use the inner html/text for the caption, just like you do for links `<a href="...">Link text</a>`.

```
<button value="Commit"></button>
<br />
<button>Commit</button>
```

**Button Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/t9etS/

**Fixed sample from the comments**
http://jsfiddle.net/APqgz/2/

Comment: "display: inline-block; or float: left;" doesn't work? http://jsfiddle.net/APqgz/

Comment: @yeeen That is because `display` is a value for the `style` attribute, too. I fixed that for you: http://jsfiddle.net/APqgz/2/

Comment: Seriously, please leave a comment why you downvote. This answer helped _yeeen_. If you think, that this answer is not helpful or can  be improved, then post a comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not set the style of your divs to be:

```
display: inline-block; float: left;
```

Comment: You don't need an `inline-block` if you use `float: left`

Answer (score 1):

Set the css rule "display: inline-block" on the DIVs you want to be side by side.

Your DIVs will need to have a width set for this to work though.

Answer (score 1):

may be these is how you put two divs side by side

```
 <div style="float:left"> hello </div>
 <div style="float:left"> world </div>
```

May be even these work

```
<input type="button" value="commit">
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, "Commit" isn't going to show up on your BUTTON since it's not an *INPUT* type button. BUTTONs don't have an attribute for value.

If you want your BUTTON to have the text "Commit" use this JavaScript:

```
yourButton.innerHTML = "Commit";
```

To sum up the flame war below, here is a better way to do it.

```
yourButton.appendChild( document.createTextNode( 'Commit' ));
```

Comment: You don't make any sense. `innerHTML` sets an elements *html*, not it's text. Displaying the text is a side effect of putting no tags around the text. http://jsfiddle.net/RvgrW/ for how to actually set an element's text.

Comment: `innerHTML` is the DOM's `eval`. Instead of calling `eval` and having the side effect do what you want, why don't you just do what you want?

Comment: *Opinion*? That's not my opinion. That's a fact. What do you think `innerHTML` does? It calls the html parser, that takes the html and turns it into DOM nodes. And look, the parser didn't find any tags surrounding a text block, so it *assumes* you just want the text. It then cleans the entire element's html and replace it with your text. It *is* the DOM's eval, literally. So instead of using `eval`, use the DOM methods for their intended use, and not some crappy hack an IE guy invented because he was lazy.

Comment: You want a link to the Webkit source code? Or do you just want to think and realize that you can't turn an html string -> DOM nodes without calling an html parser?

Comment: Just a link to a reputable source confirming your claim will do. Thanks.

Comment: -1 for promoting the piece of shit that is `innerHTML`. @Matt I'm a reputable source. And I claim innerHTML is a piece of shit.

Comment: [Here's](http://www.ericvasilik.com/2006/07/code-karma.html) the guy who made innerHTML, talking about how crappy it is. Happy?

Comment: Not sure where the down votes are coming from. I'm pretty sure this solves one of the OPs problems and and I fixed my answer so that it shows the better practice than using innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't use `value` for a button element. They are containers, so you'd be better of using this:

```
Div.buttonCommit.textContent="Commit";
```

Also, you don't need to set the type, because it is a button element. You were probably confusing it with the `input` element, where setting the `value` and the `type` would work fine.

Second, a `div` always takes up entire lines. You can see it with [examples](http://jsfiddle.net/CEEk3/), like setting its background color. So you may want to use a `span` instead. However, there is a solution which uses a div.

Like others have said, you can set the `float` style property to left to prevent a div from taking up an entire line. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/CEEk3/1/). That works, but as you can see it messes with the other text that may be present on the page.

For your code, the following works:

```
div.style.float = 'left';
```

[Working example with your code fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/awzu3/). I've added the textContent of 'div' to your `div` elements to make it clear that they're divs.

Comment: but in the working example u provide, the divs r not together

Comment: Without type="button", the default value for a BUTTON tag is "submit" in most browsers which would cause the browser to submit the page - Maybe this isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: You're right. I probably shouldn't have suggested removing the `type` attribute. However, this should work fine because the button element isn't in a form tag, so it has nowhere to submit to.